# Sempre preciso fazer clean e rebuild no visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Estou com um problema na minha solution no visual studio 2012.

Sempre que preciso debuggar e cair num break point, eu preciso dar clean e rebuild na minha solution, caso contrário ele roda, mas não para nos break point

O projeto tem 4 class library e 15 web projects, usando o TFS para controle de versão

Alguém já passou por isso e sabe a solução desse problema?

Comment: Está executando como administrador?

Comment: Sim, como administrador

Comment: Me lembro dos tempos sombrios quando tinha que usar esta ferramenta, ela criava um arquivo oculto com propriedades do projeto, só que quando eu mexia d+ com breakpoints, o visual studio tinha um bug que fazia estes arquivos de propriedades ficarem gigantes, era algum leak. Isso também fazia os breakpoints não funcionarem, ou não serem carregados corretamente. Poder ser `.suo`, `.sdf` ou outra extensão cujo arquivo esteja oculto e que seja de um tamanho razoável. Recomendo apagá-los e ver se volta ao normal.

Comment: Bugs: http://blog.richardszalay.com/2010/01/25/massive-suo-file-causes-visual-studio-to-hang-when-doing-pretty-much-anything/ 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e58cd8c6-306d-4668-a4b1-a1bd033547dd/starting-and-stopping-debugging-session-is-slow-er-than-usual?forum=vsdebug

Answer (score 1):

Repare se o seu breakpoint encontra-se com a cor sólida. Acontece em alguns casos onde você faz alteração no código fonte, e você inicia o debug anexando o processo manualmente, e de fato isso requer que você execute o build da aplicação novamente, nesses casos a notificação abaixo é informada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está, e não aparece essa mensagem.

Answer (score 0):

Já tive problemas, faz um bom tempo, com mistura de tipos de referências dentro do mesmo projeto. Se for este o seu caso, faça com que todas as referências dentro do mesmo projeto sejam referências de projeto, ao invés de fazer referência diretamente para DLLs.

Me lembro que faziamos referências de DLL para DLLs que eram compiladas raramente, mas que estavam dentro do mesmo projeto, para fazer a compilação ficar mais rápida. Ai os breakpoints ficavam malucos, pois às vezes um projeto fazia referência e de projeto e outro não, ai o breakpoint aparecia todo preenchido, mas parava nele de forma intermitente.

Não sei se isso ainda ocorre com as versões mais novas do VS, mas vale a pena verificar suas referências.